# Boolean to number in Lua

Tags: lua, boolean

Is there a way to get 1 with true and 0 with false in Lua?
There is the `tobool` which gives true or false with 1 or 0, but `tonumber` gives a nil value with true or false.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can combine `and` and `or` clauses like ternary operators.

```
function bool_to_number(value)
  return value and 1 or 0
end
```

Comment: Is this possible tu do it without using a function? like in a print()

Comment: @HellProtection `print(value and 1 or 0)`

Comment: It should be noted that this solution (although practically useful in most cases) treats any value as true and also treats `nil` as `false` which may not be what the OP wanted, in which case lhf's solution is more accurate.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this:

```
bool_to_number={ [true]=1, [false]=0 }

print(bool_to_number[value])
```

Or this:

```
debug.setmetatable(true, {__len = function (value) return value and 1 or 0 end})

print(#true)
print(#false)
```

Comment: Why `true > false` does not equal to `true` in Lua?  In many programming languages booleans are ordered set of 2 values.

Comment: Why should it? It would rather see this property as quirks of these languages. Sure, you can abuse this, but I guess it is not intended to do this in any language. If you need this, my first impression is you are doing something where there perhaps is a better method.

Comment: @pschulz - So, everything you don't understand is a quirk? Booleans should be ordered for consistency.  Approaches working with numbers should work with booleans too.

Comment: Relax, I only stated my opinion. Please explain to me why you think this makes sense. What does `true > false` mean, anyway? I can't think of a scenario where using this would be the right way to do something. Sure, you can use it, it works fine in some languages. But i don't think this is a feature lua is missing. Furthermore, you rarely need booleans in lua, since you can almost always check your objects against `nil`.

Comment: @pschulz - Let me repeat: **Booleans should be ordered for consistency**  That is, any function applicable to any ordered set (numbers, strings, comparable user objects, etc.) should work with Booleans too.  But currently in Lua `a < b` raises "attempt to compare two boolean values" error, that's a language design bug. The obvious workaround `(not a) and b` does not solve the problem to treat Booleans as ordered set with a consistent syntax.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Interesting, I haven't seen it this way. I can see where you are coming from, but I still disagree. 3 is bigger than 1, anyone can see this, it 'just makes sense'. Also is 'foo' > 'bar', if you consider something like lexicographical sorting. But I can't wrap my head around that true is bigger than false. It is not. It is also not smaller, it is the wrong questions to ask. And furthermore: I have never sorted bools, and I can't imagine why I would want to do that. And if it's needed, I'll write a comparison function for that.

Comment: @pschulz - Yes, booleans must have their own lexicographical ordering.  Glad you understood it.

Comment: @pschulz "I have never sorted bools, and I can't imagine why I would want to do that." A common case is sorting a collection of objects based on a boolean property.  For example, you want to show active products before retired ones, so you sort by isActive, descending.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from hjpotter92 takes any value different to nil as a true value (returning 1). This instead takes the value true or false.

```
local value = true
print(value == true and 1 or value == false and 0)
-- we add the false check because it would drop 0 in case it was nil
```

If you want to use a function instead, this would be it

```
local value = true
local function bool_to_number(value)
 return value == true and 1 or value == false and 0
end

print(bool_to_number(value))
```